# Is it ok to use Optional.ofNullable for checking if null and assigning default value

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

My code reads some configuration values from DB. In case they are undefined (returned null by getValueFromDB method) I want to default them to values defined in config file.

Is it ok to use `Optional.ofNullable().OrElse()` for all occurrences of `getValueFromDB()` to do null check and assign default value in case of null. 
Or will this be a misuse/abuse of `Optional` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a small abuse, but I don't feel strongly about it.  Maybe if enough programmers start doing this, it will become an accepted idiom.

But you can do the same thing without using `Optional`:

```
public static <T> T useValueOrDefault(T value, T defaultValue) {
    return (value == null) ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

and use this method everywhere instead of `Optional.ofNullable(value).orElse(default)`.  (*Note: not tested*)

I do find that built-in constructs that accomplish this, like `||` in Javascript or `?:` in Kotlin, are useful.  Too bad Java doesn't have an equivalent (**EDIT:** according to @Holger's comment, Java 9 has introduced one).

Comment: I hardly agree with Kotlin choice of `?:` or any other languages that use `?` or `!` - it's either like your code is screaming or you are using an optional group all the time.

Comment: `default` is a keyword, I'll change it

Comment: And starting with Java 9, [such method exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-). But note the semantic difference: `Objects.requireNonNullElse` will throw a `NullPointerException` if both arguments are `null`, instead of silently proceeding with a `null` result (as having a guaranteed non-`null` result is the primary purpose).

Answer (score 4):

Well, *we* use this idiom in our code base like crazy - I see no problem what-so-ever with it. This is what `Optional` is all about to me - forcing you to take an action if some value is present or not; what I absolutely love is that it is build in the language itself as of java-8 and I don't have to introduce *additional* methods for that (or libraries like `guava`).

You might be thinking for this simple case here, but `Optional` has *other* chained method as-well obviously, so I can do:

```
Optional.ofNullalbe(dbPass)
        .map(// do mapping)
        .filter(// do filtering)
        .ifPresent(x -> // log it )
```

You can't easily achieve that with *other methods*.

Answer (score 1):

It feels excessively ornate to convert something to an `Optional` only to *immediately* convert it back to the wrapped type using `orElse` in the same method.

To me `Optional` is more about exposing the possibility that a returned value might be empty, in a method's type signature. The `Optional` type communicates to the consumer that it might be empty. If you created it with `ofNullable` on the previous line of code, you are both the creator and the consumer, and already know that it might be `null` -- so deal with it in-place without creating a new short-lived object.

---

However, `Optional` fosters tidy code, and my first instinct is to ask whether your database API has the ability to return `Optional.empty()` instead of `null`, itself. This depends on the library you're using, and is possibly more likely in 2020 than it was when you asked the question in 2017.

In that case it would make perfect sense to use `returnedOptional.orElse(default)` if that's the application logic.

---

If your database API can't give you an `Optional`, I wouldn't, in the application logic, go via `Optional` to do the defaulting. It's simpler and clearer to use:

```
return value == null ? default : value;
```

---

However I *would* consider adding a thin abstraction layer between your Optional-incapable database API and your application logic, that just does `Optional.ofNullable()` where appropriate. *Their* DB library doesn't have the API you want, so wrap it to create the API you want. *Your* DB library has the courtesy to the caller, that when a value might be absent, the type signature says so.

So instead of:

```
MyType maybeS = theirDbLibrary.query(...);
MyType s = (maybeS == null) ? default : maybeS;
```

You'd have:

```
Optional<MyType> maybeS = myWrappedDbLibrary.query(...);
MyType s = maybeS.orElse(default);
```

The intent here is to remove all knowledge of `null` from your application logic. If the core of your application has no reference to `null` at all (including `ofNullable`), that's really great. It removes lots and lots of opportunities for bugs. But for that to be possible you need to eliminate the possibility that a `null` gets passed into your code -- and that's where your clean-up layer between the DB and your application code does its work.